# Setting up a crontab on debian/LINUX server

Tags: linux, drupal-7, debian, cron

I am trying to set up a crontab for a drupal 7 site. I installed elysia cron to schedule it and if I force it to run it runs fine. However I am having difficulty setting it up to call the cron.php file .

This is what I have on my crontab -e

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  "/var/www/test.ccc.com/cron.php"
```

And this is the error that I have been getting on my var/mail

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(/home/neela/includes/bootstrap.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test.ccc.com/cron.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/home/neela/includes/bootstrap.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/test.ccc.com/cron.php on line 13
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function drupal_bootstrap() in /var/www/test.ccc.com/cron.php on line 14
```

Also my test.ccc.com server is not live yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: does /home/neela/includes/bootstrap.inc exist and is accesible by the user running the crontab? Seems like cron.php is having trouble including it

Comment: @marianosimone  /home/neela/includes/bootstrap.inc doesnt exist. bootsrap.inc its inside the folder /var/www/test.ccc.com/includes/bootstrap.inc

Comment: Could you share /var/www/test.ccc.com/cron.php? (in particular, around line 13, where the inclusion seems to fail)

Comment: @marianosimone   define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()); include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';

Comment: seems like DRUPAL_ROOT is somehow expanding to /home/neela, so PHP is trying to load that file from there. How are you setting DRUPAL_ROOT? Is that variable available to the user running the crontab?

Comment: I used this on my crontab    */1 * * * * wget  http://test.ccc.com/cron.php?cron_key=cronkey and its working fine now